# Android Accessibility Service: Open Accessibility Menu

Tags: android, accessibility, accessibilityservice

With TalkBack on, a user (who is able) can swipe up and right to open the "Accessibility Menu":

[image: Accessibility Menu]

Now I have written an [Accessibility Service](https://github.com/qbalsdon/accessibility_broadcast_dev), with the goal of [acting on behalf of the user](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/service#act-for-users). As far as I can tell, this type of action is permitted within an accessibility service:

> Starting with Android 4.0 (API Level 14), accessibility services can act on behalf of users, including changing the input focus and selecting (activating) user interface elements. In Android 4.1 (API Level 16) the range of actions has been expanded to include scrolling lists and interacting with text fields. Accessibility services can also take global actions, such as navigating to the Home screen, pressing the Back button, opening the notifications screen and recent applications list. Android 4.1 also includes a new type of focus, Accessibilty Focus, which makes all visible elements selectable by an accessibility service.
>
> These new capabilities make it possible for developers of accessibility services to create alternative navigation modes such as gesture navigation, and give users with disabilities improved control of their Android devices.

I followed the codelab which gives the following example of performing a gesture on behalf of the user:

```
private void configureSwipeButton() {
   Button swipeButton = (Button) mLayout.findViewById(R.id.swipe);
   swipeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {
           Path swipePath = new Path();
           swipePath.moveTo(1000, 1000);
           swipePath.lineTo(100, 1000);
           GestureDescription.Builder gestureBuilder = new GestureDescription.Builder();
           gestureBuilder.addStroke(new GestureDescription.StrokeDescription(swipePath, 0, 500));
           dispatchGesture(gestureBuilder.build(), null, null);
       }
   });
}
```

[SOURCE](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/developing-android-a11y-service?hl=th#7)

However, if I try to do a combined gesture on the accessibility service, to open the menu, nothing happens:

Attempt 1:

```
        val upSwipe = Path()
        upSwipe.moveTo(1000f, 1000f)
        upSwipe.lineTo(100f, 1000f)

        val rightSwipe = Path()
        rightSwipe.moveTo(100f, 1000f)
        rightSwipe.lineTo(400f, 1000f)

        val builder = GestureDescription.Builder()
        builder.addStroke(StrokeDescription(upSwipe, 0, 500, true))
        builder.addStroke(StrokeDescription(rightSwipe, 500, 500, false))
        dispatchGesture(builder.build(), null, null)
```

Attempt 2:

```
        val upSwipe = Path()
        upSwipe.moveTo(1000f, 1000f)
        upSwipe.lineTo(100f, 1000f)

        val rightSwipe = Path()
        rightSwipe.moveTo(100f, 1000f)
        rightSwipe.lineTo(400f, 1000f)

        val combinedSwipe = GestureDescription.Builder()
        combinedSwipe.addStroke(
            StrokeDescription(upSwipe, 0, 500, true).apply {
                continueStroke(rightSwipe, 500, 500, false)
            }
        )
        dispatchGesture(combinedSwipe.build(), null, null)
```

Attempt 3:

```
        val swipePath = Path()
        swipePath.moveTo(1000f, 1000f)
        swipePath.lineTo(100f, 1000f)
        swipePath.lineTo(400f, 1000f)
        val gestureBuilder = GestureDescription.Builder()
        gestureBuilder.addStroke(StrokeDescription(swipePath, 0, 500))
        dispatchGesture(gestureBuilder.build(), null, null)
```

The real goal here is to open the Accessibility Menu, not necessarily perform the gesture (as these gestures can be changed by the user).

Answer (score 0):

I found this in an Open Source project, it's in Kotlin, and is a funtional function:

```
/**
 * Perform the provided click on the current activity.
 *
 * @param click the click to be performed.
 */
private fun performClick(click: ClickInfo) {
    val clickPath = Path()
    val clickBuilder = GestureDescription.Builder()

    clickPath.moveTo(click.from!!.x.toFloat(), click.from!!.y.toFloat())
    when (click.type) {
        ClickInfo.SINGLE -> {
            clickBuilder.addStroke(StrokeDescription(clickPath, 0, 1))
        }
        ClickInfo.SWIPE -> {
            clickPath.lineTo(click.to!!.x.toFloat(), click.to!!.y.toFloat())
            clickBuilder.addStroke(StrokeDescription(clickPath, 0, 175))
        }
    }

    dispatchGesture(clickBuilder.build(), null, null)
}
```

this is the original source:
https://github.com/Nain57/Smart-AutoClicker

regards

Comment: Thank you for the attempted answer, but this (or modifying this) won't yield the correct outcome. I use exactly the same mechanism for creating gestures in my AccessibilityService as this code. It's also documented in my question (attempt 1). It's a multi-line swipe that's the issue. Google seems to have conceded that this is a bug with TalkBack: https://issuetracker.google.com/u/2/issues/185631661